# Mixed mode assembly issue in a class library

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, class-library, mixed-mode

I have a common problem with a unique twist.  I am running VS2010 and using a cluster of 3rd party DLLs that must have been compiled in a previous framework. Of course I get the following error:

**Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.**

I've solved the issue before with these DLLs in a Windows Forms Application by adding the following to an app.config file:

```
<configuration> 
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

My problem now is that I wish to use these DLLs in a Class Library project that can then be called by a windows service.  Unfortunately class libraries don't use app.config files.  I've scoured Google for hours and haven't been able to find a useful solution, so any assistance would be very appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?  We have a similar problem with a COM-enabled class library that is being used with legacy VB6 applications.  Adding the startup configuration option with the supportedRuntime doesn't work.